# Issue in Transaction Scope inside WCF

Tags: wcf, transactions, transactionscope

In my Project, DAL Is WCF service .Net4.0. using database oracle 11g. I am using transaction scope in WCF(server side).
I have to call more than one Stored  procedure inside the method(operation contract) if any one sp failed, I need to rollback already executed sp. But rollback not happened. I am not used client side transaction flow.

I have placed sample code

public class Service : IService
{

```
public bool Method1()
    {
        using (TransactionScope Scope1 = new TransactionScope())
        {
            Method2();
            Method3();
            Scope1.Complete();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Method2()
    {
        using (TransactionScope Scope2 = new TransactionScope())
        {
            // Procedure call .....
            Scope2.Complete();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Method3()
    {
        using (TransactionScope Scope3 = new TransactionScope())
        {
            // Procedure call .....
            Scope3.Complete();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

}

Comment: could you post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work as expected, the way you have your code laid out there.

However if you are using WCF, you might want to consider using the transaction flow stuff built in to WCF. You can wrap the entire WCF call into a single transaction that way, without manually creating and managing TransactionScopes. The WCF transaction flow can be set up to require a transaction at the service side, so WCF will start a transaction for you if the client doesn't pass one. This way you wouldn't have to edit your client at all.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751413.aspx

Comment: My understanding is WCF is not a factor as the transaction is on the service side, no transaction is flowing between client and server. Have you thought about profiling the SQL to see when the begin/end transaction calls are being executed on the server?

Comment: @Rich - I agree that WCF is not really a factor here, however he said he was using it, so I recommended using the transaction flow instead, just because then you can rely on WCF to make 1 transaction scope on its own, instead of manually setting each one up, and worrying about nesting them, and calling Complete.  The manual-setup approach is definitely more error-prone. Tracing the begin/end transaction is definitely a good idea too.